# Get user's login duration time without time of locked screen

Tags: linux, users, login, time

I'd like to get information about "utilization time" of users on linux sytems for specific days. This means the time, an user has an unlocked screen. In contrast the command `ac` displays the whole time, a user is logged in, including the time with locked screen or standby.

As far as I knows, the idle time displayed by `who` command differs from the time with unlocked screen. So that's apparently not the solution.

The open source progam *Timekpr* displays the wanted information, but only for the current week. May be it is possible to extract the code for that calculation. However, my programming skills are too bad for that.

Answer (score 0):

> As far as I knows, the idle time displayed by who command differs from the time with unlocked screen.

No. `who` is a program that predates graphical sessions. It has no notion at all what a "locked screen" is.

Generally, a screen locker is just an ordinary program that happens to run in full screen and capture all your key presses. So, from your computer's point of view, a user never logs out – its just not doing much during the time the lockscreen is shown.

In recent years, luckily most Linux distros came to somewhat of an agreement how user session and seat management looks like – so there's `loginctl lock-session` (and your session manager can call that internally or through dbus to lock).

You *could* write a program that hooks the lock/unlock mechanism via dbus and takes note of the times in between – as far as I know, nothing does this yet: `loginctl session-status` has a notion of the *age* of a session, but not of how long it's been assigned to a seat and unlocked.

Generally, that information you're looking for seems of very questionable use – for accounting purposes, the user might do arbitrary compute/network/storage-intense things while the screen is locked.

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly what you're asking for, but you might find the [GNU accounting utilities (acct)](https://www.gnu.org/software/acct/) useful.

> GNU Accounting Utilities is a set of utilities which reports and summarizes
> data about user connect times and process execution statistics.
>
> "Login accounting" provides summaries of system resource usage based on
> connect time, and "process accounting" provides summaries based on the
> commands executed on the system.

It should be available packaged for most distros - e.g. on Debian, etc, `apt-get install acct`

Note: keeping track of users and their processes and execution times etc can impact performance....probably not significant on a lightly-loaded high-end system, but could be quite noticeable on a heavily-loaded or low-end system.